# How to identify and fill I shape Contours in javacv?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I'm developing project on javacv and I need to know how to identify following image and fill that Image using particular color ?

I try to go through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240344/how-to-identify-polygon-using-opencv-or-javacv) and This is the image that I use

[image]

I try to go through this code and I developed a code in javacv

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import static com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class PolyGonIdentification {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CanvasFrame cnvs=new CanvasFrame("Polygon");
        cnvs.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        CvMemStorage storage=CvMemStorage.create();
        CvSeq squares = new CvContour();
        squares = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvContour.class), sizeof(CvSeq.class), storage);
        JFileChooser f=new JFileChooser();
        int result=f.showOpenDialog(f);//show dialog box to choose files
        File myfile=null;
        String path="";
        if(result==0){
            myfile=f.getSelectedFile();//selected file taken to myfile
            path=myfile.getAbsolutePath();//get the path of the file
        }
        IplImage src = cvLoadImage(path);//hear path is actual path to image
        IplImage gry=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
        cvCvtColor(src, gry, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvThreshold(gry, gry, 230, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        cvFindContours(gry, storage, squares, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),    CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        System.out.println(squares.total());
        for (int i=0; i<squares.total(); i++)
        {
            cvDrawContours(gry, squares, CvScalar.ONE, CvScalar.ONE, 127, 1, 8);
        }
        IplConvKernel mat=cvCreateStructuringElementEx(7, 7, 3, 3, CV_SHAPE_RECT,    null);
        cvDilate(gry, gry, mat, CV_C);
        cvErode(gry, gry, mat, CV_C);
        cnvs.showImage(gry);

    }
}
```

My final result should be like this image

[image]

Put above code resulted this kind of image. Please can some one help me to resolve this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive that using this code

```
    import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
    import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
    import static com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.*;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

    public class Ishape {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            CanvasFrame cnvs=new CanvasFrame("Polygon");
            cnvs.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            CvMemStorage storage=CvMemStorage.create();
            CvSeq squares = new CvContour();
            squares = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvContour.class), sizeof(CvSeq.class), storage);
            JFileChooser f=new JFileChooser();
            int result=f.showOpenDialog(f);//show dialog box to choose files
                File myfile=null;
                String path="";
            if(result==0){
                myfile=f.getSelectedFile();//selected file taken to myfile
                path=myfile.getAbsolutePath();//get the path of the file
            }
            IplImage src = cvLoadImage(path);//hear path is actual path to image
            IplImage gry=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
            cvCvtColor(src, gry, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            cvThreshold(gry, gry, 230, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
            cvFindContours(gry, storage, squares, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            CvSeq ss=null;
            for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
            {
                cvDrawContours(gry, squares, CvScalar.WHITE, CV_RGB(248, 18, 18), 1, -1, 8);
                ss=cvApproxPoly(squares, sizeof(CvContour.class), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, 8, 0);
            }
            IplConvKernel mat=cvCreateStructuringElementEx(7, 7, 3, 3, CV_SHAPE_RECT, null);
            cvDilate(gry, gry, mat, CV_C);
            cvErode(gry, gry, mat, CV_C);
            cnvs.showImage(gry);

        }
    }
```

Result

[image]

This will be resulted out put and I believe this might help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code does exactly what is supposed to do:

```
// as stated [in the answer to your previous question][1], findContours leaves gry set to 0, or black
cvFindContours(gry, storage, squares, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),   
         CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); 

    System.out.println(squares.total()); // nothing interesting

    for (int i = 0; i < squares.total(); i++)
    {
        // draw a gray contour (127) on a black image
        cvDrawContours(gry, squares, CvScalar.ONE, CvScalar.ONE, 127, 1, 8);
    }
```

To correct it, you have to set gry to 255 (white, before any call to drawContours, and draw black contours! that is 0, not 127.)

Comment: Hay could you please explain how to access the found Contours points values?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to find contours using external retrieval mode:

```
CV_RETR_EXTERNAL retrives only the extreme outer contours
```

In your situation this is the best mode because you have one external contour and this contour is what you're looking for. [Here's](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-findcontours) documantation.

After this just draw it using [drawContours](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-drawcontours) with `CV_FILLED` as thickness parameter to fill external polygon.